# xmlstarlet xslt transform failing to remove nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xmlstarlet

I'm attempting to use xmlstarlet to work on a large group of .Net project files, however attempting this simple transform using xsl to remove `ProductVersion` isn't working.

I have tried `//ProductVersion`, could the namespace in this instance be causing issues?

run.cmd

```
SET ProjFile=test.vbproj
SET TempFile=%TEMP%\temp.proj
xml tr clean.xsl %ProjFile% > %TempFile%
move /Y %TempFile% %ProjFile%
```

clean.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match='@*|node()'>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='@*|node()'/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ProductVersion"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

test.vbproj

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProductVersion>9.0.30729</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this directly with the xmlstarlet edit subcommand:

```
xmlstarlet ed \
  -N ms=http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003 \
  -d '//ms:ProductVersion' test.vbproj
```

Alternately, you can modify your XSLT to respect the namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ms="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match='@*|node()'>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='@*|node()'/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ms:ProductVersion"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```